# How do I fix my site after realising the doctype was wrong?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover, doctype

While trying to fix the hover bug in internet explorer I realised that the doctype was written wrong.
I corrected it but now the **formatting is wrong in firefox**!

The site should look like [this](http://projectstratos.com/05-02-11/) but it looks like [that](http://projectstratos.com/05-02-11-1/)

Is there any quick fix or will I have to rewrite it all manually?
Please ask if you need any code.

Comment: I don't see how changing your doctype is in any way related to changing your URLs

Comment: I think he means if you follow those two links you can see the site, with and without the doctype

Comment: Yep, I just gave the links so I could try and find a fix but other people can see what I am talking about

Comment: Which browser are you comparing them with?

Comment: the doctype doesn't make a difference in ie but in firefox.

Comment: Sorry, I am a rubish at pretty much all code! I will try my best to answer some once I get this problem sorted.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't know this was possible!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like Firefox is treating your comments that are formatted like:

```
<!-------Menu--->
```

as just the start of a comment and hence commenting out a large part of your markup.

Try changing them to

```
<!-- menu -->
```

and see if that makes a difference

Comment: so do you mean to <!--menu--> ?

Comment: yes, so make it <!-- Menu --> and similar for the others.  I've tried it on my PC now and seems to be bringing content back in as I fix the comments

Comment: ah yes... somethings happening, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As you changed the Doctype, the browser sure changed from quriks to standards mode. This means that the browser will now interpret your website strictly after W3C's Standards and won't be as fault-tolerant as before.

I'm pretty sure the rendering issues will solve once you fixed [these errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fprojectstratos.com%2F05-02-11-1%2F). If I were you, I would first try to remove those unnecessary dashes from the comments. `<!-------Example---->` to `<!-- Example -->`.

Comment: you're welcome. [W3C's validator](http://validator.w3.org) is always a good resource to check if you wrote correct HTML.

Comment: I didn't realise they could cause a problem, I have seen many tutorials where this is used!

Comment: Well, when the W3C says this kind of comments is invalid, the browsers will interpret them as invalid (if they're standards-compilant)! So probably these tutorials weren't of such a high quality. :D

Comment: Well actually they it was by phpacademy which is one of the best tutorial makers, oh well!

Comment: The layout is fine now, the only problem is the font size but that can easily be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is going to be a manual process, but you shouldn't need to do a complete rewrite.  You should be able to incrementally fix any rendering issues one by one.

Comment: Ok, is there a good refrence that would help me looking at the issues you see?